# Selling Multiple Rebranded Apps in Mobile Stores

Tags: mobile

Is it permitted to sell multiple copies of a rebranded app in the play store or apple store?  Specifically, we would be creating a tailored version of the same app for different companies that incorporates their custom business logos and style (and perhaps other feature customizations as well).

Is this permitted?

Answer (score 1):

This will only be an issue when Apple decides that you're flooding the app store, if at all. There are many factors involved in Apple's review process, but they are not public knowledge. As far as Android goes, I don't believe they have a review process as of yet. So theoretically, you can put as many versions of the same app on Play as you wish. This may someday change however, as many apps on Android are dangerous or malicious in nature.